# Event Handling in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

There is a button `btn_Edit` in a window. When that button clicked, a new window opens (`new_win`) and a click event is added to a button (`btn_OK`) on `new_win`. It seems that `btn_OK_Click` does not work because `new_win` does not close. Where is the problem?

```
    BC_edit new_win = new BC_edit();

    private void btn_Edit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        new_win.Title = "a_title";
        new_win.ShowDialog();

        new_win.btn_OK.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_OK_Click);            
    }

    private void btn_OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _MyCollection.Add(new MyData
        {
            Boundary = new_win.Title,
            Type = new_win.cmb_BC_edit_type.SelectedItem.ToString(),
            Option = new_win.cmb_BC_edit_options.SelectedItem.ToString()
        });

        new_win.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the event *before* you show the new window:

```
    new_win.btn_OK.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_OK_Click);
    new_win.ShowDialog();
```

Remember that the `ShowDialog` method is blocking: it won't return until the window is closed, so the following statements won't be executed until then.