# Close second window generated in first window's code

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm writing a WPF application in C#, which has a main window with a button called "Login". If you click it, a second window with a login form will appear. If I click the "Cancel" button in the login window, I'd like the login window to close and I'd like to return to the main window.

This is the solution I've come up with. However, since an instance of the Login window is created inside the method ButtonLogin_Click() of the main window and since the method ButtonCancel_Click() of the login window will only this.Close() it, what happens if I click the "Login" button in the main window again? Will the existing instance of the Login window be shown again, or does it create a new instance every time I click the button (which is not what I want obviously because I'll end up having n instances of the Login window if I click the Login button n times)? What is the best way to do this?

[image: Main window]

[image: Login window]

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace TestTwoWindows
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Login LoginWindow = new Login();
            LoginWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Login.xaml.cs:

```
namespace TestTwoWindows
{
    public partial class Login : Window
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: open a window as modal: `LoginWindow.Show();` -> `LoginWindow.ShowDialog();`. MainWindow will be unaccessible until LoginWindow is closed

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320393/how-to-create-a-class-which-can-only-have-a-single-instance-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @user5226582, singletone won't work well here. use case: click Login - click Cancel - click Login again. it makes more sence to create a window twice on each Login click

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of hiding instead of closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the modal dialog, you can check the null value and declare the window outside the scope of the event handler.

I think it would be nicer to reactivate the login window when you click again on the button or open it again after cancelling a login

```
    LoginWindow LoginWindow;
    private void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoginWindow == null)
        {
            LoginWindow = new LoginWindow();
            LoginWindow.Closed += Window_Closed;
            LoginWindow.Show();
        } else
        {
            LoginWindow.Activate();
        }
    }
```

and set it to null again when closed

```
    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginWindow = null;
    }
```

Comment: This will throw an exception. You should change the Visibility. See my answer.

Comment: @logithack let me know if you have any issues with this

Comment: This must work too (I was pointing to the answer before your edit). thanks

Comment: @user1892538 Could you please explain to me what the line LoginWindow.Closed += Window_Closed; does? I know that the += operator increments the preceding value by the succeeding value, but in your code it seems like the function call Window_Closed is being added to LoginWindow.Closed? I've never seen that before, so I'd be glad if you could help me a bit with this! And thanks for your reply, I think that's what I've been looking for!

Comment: The `+=` operator is *also* used to specify a method that will be called in response to an event; such methods are called *event handlers*. The use of the += operator in this context is referred to as *subscribing to an event*.

Answer (score 0):

You should not close the window. Keep the instance and set its Visibility. In other words, use this approach:

```
    Login LoginWindow;
    private void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (LoginWindow == null)
        {
            LoginWindow = new Login();
            LoginWindow.Closing += LoginWindow_Closing;
            LoginWindow.Show();
        }
        else
            LoginWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void LoginWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        ((Window)sender).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for. However, I'm not that experienced yet with GUI programming in C#. Could you please explain to me what  _LoginWindow.Closing += LoginWindow_Closing_; is about? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9711424/5615980, you can find more by googling event handling in wpf

Answer (score 0):

open a window as modal:

`LoginWindow.Show();` -> `LoginWindow.ShowDialog();`

MainWindow will be unaccessible until LoginWindow is closed